# java8 reducing a stream using accumulator and combiner

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I am trying to write a simple reduce function that will check **if all the elements of `srcList` are present in `targetList`**:

```
List<String> srcList = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
        List<String> targetList = Collections.singletonList("a");

        Boolean result = srcList.stream().reduce(true
                , (prevResult, srcElement) -> targetList.contains(srcElement)
                , (prevResult, currentResult) -> prevResult && currentResult);

System.out.println(result); // prints false as expected
```

The above mentioned lambda does not seem to be working as expected. For instance if we change the element in the target list the result is printed as true:

```
List<String> srcList = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
        List<String> targetList = Collections.singletonList("b");

        Boolean result = srcList.stream().reduce(true
                , (prevResult, srcElement) -> targetList.contains(srcElement)
                , (prevResult, currentResult) -> prevResult && currentResult);

System.out.println(result); // prints true
```

It looks like that the expression is returning the result of last `accumulator` evaluation only (i.e. the contains operation in this case) and the combiner is not performing the `&&` on all the results.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: Easier? `targetList.containsAll(srcList)`

Comment: @AndyTurner : Yes, am aware about that but just wanted to know the issue with the above mentioned lambda.

Comment: If this is an exercise in streams, but not specifically an exercise in `reduce(...)`, then a better way would be: `srcList.stream().allMatch(targetList::contains)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you ignore `prevResult` in the accumulator:

```
(prevResult, srcElement) -> targetList.contains(srcElement)
```

should be, for example

```
(prevResult, srcElement) -> prevResult && targetList.contains(srcElement)
```

---

But honestly, it would be easier to use `containsAll`:

```
targetList.containsAll(srcList)
```

Comment: I was going to post this as an answer, but then I noticed the accumulator parameter's documentation: `an associative, non-interfering, stateless function for incorporating an additional element into a result`. Is the function still considered stateless if it depends on the value of the previous result?

Comment: @JacobG. Yes, because the result is a function of the inputs only.

Comment: @AndyTurner: but then the what's the role of a combiner in this case? is it only significant for parallel streams?

Comment: @gaurs the combiner is only used if the stream is a parallel stream: the stream is split, and the partial result is computed over each fragment; the combiner is used to combine fragments.